# SO "answered xxx minutes ago"

Tags: bug, status-completed, live-refresh

Recently, I am seeing this issue frequently.

I answered a question. And I was on same page for couple of minutes. I see the following beneath my answer

> answered 17 minutes ago

I certainly knew it is wrong because I've answered just a while ago. I tried to reload the page. Then I got

> answered 5 minutes ago

This is happening for comments too.

what's the reason?

Comment: I see exactly the same phenomenon, so I don't know why this question was downvoted.

Comment: I guess the error is in javascript that updates the duration. when page is loaded, it is correct. but when duration updates automatically (w/o page refresh), this gets mad :). -1 to downvoter :P

Comment: ok, i see this is happening in Chrome (v23x). When I use Firefox (v3.6x and v14x) live refresh is not working at all.

Comment: I've got SeaMonkey 13.0 here, but I haven't tested on any other browsers.

Comment: It doesn't happen with IE 9. But then, IE seems to like SO better when it's in compatibility mode, so it could be that it disabled live refresh too. Maybe I should do more testing.

Answer (score 3):

We had a time offset issue with some web servers at our secondary data center in Oregon (which the sites are currently being served from - FYVM Sandy).  The clocks are now right and we shouldn't see this again.

If you see this again, please comment here!